# Fail to import avro schema with python3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, avro

from python prompt:

```
>>> import avro
>>> import avro.schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'avro.schema'

>>> print(avro)
<module 'avro' (namespace)>
>>> print(avro.schema)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'avro' has no attribute 'schema'
```

specs:

- deb9 x64, Python 3.6.4 and avro-python3 Version: 1.8.2, pip 9.0.1
- virtualenv activated and avro got pip installed

is avro maintained or should i use fastavro, how to solve above, cant run basic examples from [quickstart](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html)

Comment: Indeed, I have the same problem too on Mac Os with Python3.7.

Answer (score 5):

Check your requirements.
It might be `avro==1.8.2` 
The above error was coming for this requirement.
Changing the requirement to:
`avro-python3==1.8.2` solved the problem for me.

Used `pip install avro-python3` instead of `pip install avro`

Comment: I also had this with `avro-python3==1.9.2.1`. I downgraded to `avro-python3==1.9.2` and now it is working fine